# Alignment of raster files(.tif)

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, simulation

I have 5 different .tif files and all of them have the same bounding box(same starting and ending coordinates), but the number of rows/columns are different in each one of them. I want to make the number of rows and columns the same for each of the tif file so that they could be used for my simulation.

I am working with POSTGIS database .

Note - There are no holes in the tif file.

[image: Different columns or rows]

Comment: Removed ArcGIS Desktop tag, because Esri doesn't support rasters in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do you have .tif files, or rasters stored in PostGIS? Those are different things.